# If statement gives different error depending on variables in bash

Tags: bash

I have some bash code (sorry about the formatting, Stack Overflow didn't work):

```
read -p "Start server and create configuration files (y or n)?  : " startserver
if [ $startserver = "y" ]
        then java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
elif [ $startserver = "n" ]
        then exit 0
        else invalid;
fi
```

It generates should say "Invalid!" when I input something other than y or n. It does that when there are no spaces in the input. If I make the input one space, I get the following error:

```
/home/snuggles08/Documents/CraftBukkit Installer.sh: line 5: [: =: unary operator expected
/home/snuggles08/Documents/CraftBukkit Installer.sh: line 7: [: =: unary operator expected
```

When the text has spaces, I get the following error:

```
/home/snuggles08/Documents/CraftBukkit Installer.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments
/home/snuggles08/Documents/CraftBukkit Installer.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments
```

Why is this?

Comment: use `"$startserver"` instead of `$startserver`

Comment: The line numbers in the error messages don't seem to line up with the code.

Comment: Use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` in your `if` statements.

Comment: You're quoting the wrong thing.  `y` is absolutely guaranteed to be the string `y`, so there is no need for quotes.  `$startserver` may contain special characters or spaces, so it should be protected.  In other words, write `"$startserver" = y`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico That was the code that wasn't working.

Comment: Just get in the habit of always quoting your variables, unless you have a specific reason not to. There are times when it's not necessary, but it doesn't hurt to add unnecessary quotes.